# calling void sync method from Async - Cannot await void

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2

I am implementing ExceptionLogger for WebApi, where exceptions are logged into database.

```
 public class CustomExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override async Task LogAsync(ExceptionLoggerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       var log = new Logger();
       await log.LogMessage(context.Exception); --Cannot await 'void' complie time error here
    }
}

public class Logger
{
   public void LogMessage(Exception ex)
   {
     //code to insert message into db
   }
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Why do you need `LogAsync` to be async?

Comment: `await Task.Run(()=> log.LogMessage(context.Exception))` ?

Comment: @Yacoub Massad - Since my logmessage involves database operation, i want my LogAsync to be async

Comment: Currently `logmessage` is synchronous. Even if it involves database operations, they are synchronous operations. If you truly want to make these methods asynchronous, you need to do it all the way. I.e., you need to make the database operations themselves asynchronous.

Comment: @coder: You'll find that `async` adoption works best if you approach it the opposite way. That is, first make your "leaves" call async APIs and `await` them, then make the containing methods `async` and `await` them, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you truly want LogMessage() to be async and awaitable, you will need to change your code to look something like this:

```
public class Logger
{
   public async Task LogMessage(Exception ex)
   {
     //code to insert message into db
   }
}
```

For it to be of any use, your database insert code should also be async.

Comment: If the database operations are not done asynchronously, what benefit would one get by wrapping the synchronous code with `Task.Run` and then await it?

Comment: Your edit does not fix the problem. You are still wrapping synchronous code with `Task.Run`. Take a look at this: http://www.ben-morris.com/why-you-shouldnt-create-asynchronous-wrappers-with-task-run/

Comment: Well, true.  Really, if it's not async all the way down to the db insert, then there's really no point in any of this.  Probably best just to remove the Task.Run bit to remove confusion